# Tunneling apache zeppelin from EMR to localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, apache-zeppelin

I've launched an EMR cluster on AWS with spark and zeppelin, and i'd like to forward the connection to localhost:8890.
I'm using windows[image]

so I use putty. The connection works, but when I try localhost:8890 i get nowhere.

is there somthing I'm missing?

here are the security rules:

[image]

Comment: Where do you type "localhost:8890"? Are you typing that in your browser?

Comment: @error2007s I type it in the web browser...

Comment: Can you paste your security group rules for your EC2 instance? And also check if your windows is not blocking the port 8890.

Comment: Ok you need to add 8890 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 security rule to security group and then check it will work

Answer (score 0):

stupid issue - i've connected the slave node instead of the master node...